# Bash Issue When Terminal Opens

Tags: bash

Whenever I open Terminal I get the following messages:

```
bash: /etc/profile.d/sm.sh: No such file or directory
bash: /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh: No such file or directory
```

These don't seem to impact anything but are incredibly annoying.

Comment: What's your question? Is `~/.bashrc` referencing those files?

Comment: Most likely one of ~/.bashrc, /etc/bashrc, or /etc/profile is trying to source them.

Comment: Kevin, so how do I remove them prom the prompt?

Answer (score 1):

The entry will be in one of the dot files which are run when you open a new terminal or login.
In your home directory you will find the entry in one of

```
.profile
.bashrc
.bash_profile
```

If it's not in there it could be in the system wide start file /etc/profile.